# Google Closure library as a flowchart constructor

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

So I am very interested in using the closure libraries more at my workplace, but my boss is telling me it seems "too scattered and complicated to use". His main concern is that it won't be able to replace our workflow constructor and I have searched the web far and wide for an example of using the the drag functionality to connect one or more boxes but seem to be unable to do this without using a canvas.

So I turn to you my dear Stackexchangers, if you should be having just the tidbit of code I need to tie it all together or a brilliant idea I can work on to make an easy showcase that will make my boss rethink the use of the closure libraries. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do with closure, but I found this library that is much simpler and easier to use out of the box, that will integrate well into the closure library.
http://raphaeljs.com/